# Как начать исчисление списка v-for с единицы во Vue.js?

Tags: веб-программирование, vue.js, for

Нужно сделать так, чтобы index в списке v-for начался с единицы.

```html
<tr v-for="(item,index) in num">
    <td data-label="Период">
        {{index}}
    </td>
    <td data-label="Деньги на данном периоде">
        {{money[index]}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: заменить `num`, на `num.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td data-label="Период">
    {{index+1}}
</td>
```

Comment: хорошо, я недавно на сайте